# How to sync calendars programmatically?

Tags: php, facebook, calendar, google-calendar-api

I'd like to hear some ideas how to sync calendar events. Say I have two calendars having fields (id, title, start, end). But I don't have updated field over there, so I think I need to use separate storage to temporary store data for syncing. I haven't done this before so I don't really know where to start. For example weather to compare both titles and times, or just times, how to select the main event and which way to copy. I'm going to use PHP as a programming language and actually events at the moment comes from Google Calendars and Facebook events but I rather make it work more universally, at least supporting iCal format.

Comment: There is no real question here - what have you tried?  People will not do the work/research for you.  Take a stab at it and come back with a more specific question (if there are any).

Comment: Do you know a forum for exchanging programming problems on general level rather than specific then? Usually when I have a specific question I get an answer from Google and after few tests rather easily.

Comment: Get started and see what problems you run into.

Comment: Yes, there is a forum just for that.  It's part of StackExchange family of sites.  http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right place to ask this sort of question was on other forum as advised by DMCS: 
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/129115/how-to-sync-calendars-events-programmatically/129116